# Two input pipes through file descriptor shuffling and /dev/fd

Tags: shell, io-redirection, ksh, file-descriptors

I want to pipe two programs into one. If my shell supports it, I can use [Process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).
For example, to list the common lines of two files in indifferent order, I can use

```
comm -12 <(sort a) <(sort b)
```

However process substitution doesn't exist in plain `sh`. I can do it with full POSIX portability by creating a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), but this is cumbersome as it requires finding a directory for the FIFO and cleaning up afterwards. A good practical compromise is to use two shell pipe constructs and use file descriptor shuffling to move one pipe to another file descriptor, then use `/dev/fd` to designate the pipe, which works on most Unix variants:

```
sort a | { exec 3<&0; sort b | comm -12 /dev/fd/0 /dev/fd/3; }
```

This works in dash, bash, BusyBox sh, etc. but not in ksh93 and mksh. Why?

```
$ mksh -c 'sort a | { exec 3<&0; sort b | comm -12 /dev/fd/0 /dev/fd/3; }'
$ ksh93 -c 'sort a | { exec 3<&0; sort b | comm -12 /dev/fd/0 /dev/fd/3; }'
comm: /dev/fd/0: No such device or address
```

Answer (score 4):

Unlike redirections on other commands, redirections on the `exec` builtin may be closed when the shell executes an external program. [POSIX allows both behaviors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec). Ksh (both ATT ksh, and pdksh and mksh) close these descriptors when they execute an external utility (i.e. for a redirection on the `exec` builtin, after calling `dup2` to perform the redirection, they set the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag on the new descriptor). The Bourne shell, dash, bash, zsh and BusyBox sh treat this redirection like any other redirection.

A more portable solution to the two-input-pipes problem (assuming the existence of `/dev/fd`) is to perform another redirection on the command that reads the input, moving the file descriptor to a new one. This extra redirection doesn't set the close-on-exec flag on the new descriptor.

```
sort a | { exec 3<&0; sort b | comm -12 /dev/fd/0 /dev/fd/4 4<&3; }
```

This works in pdksh/mksh, and in ksh93r but not in recent versions of ksh (93s+ 2008-01-31 or 93u+ 2012-08-01). I don't understand what ksh is doing there.

Comment: I think the issue with the recent versions of ksh is that you are using quite a low file descriptor (3) and ksh may have already occupied it for something else.  Overall, fd 3 is stdlog, IIRC :)